# How can I add multiple rows referring to another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Let's say I have two tables like below:

**users** table:

| user_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | kevin |
| 1 | alice |
| 2 | jake |
| 3 | mike |

**permissions** table:

| user_id | permission |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 |

And let's say that I want to add permission **5** to every single user who doesn't already have it. What would be the best MySQL query for this?

Comment: You now how to select all users that don't have permission 5? And you know that you can insert a query result? What have you tried? Or where have you got stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not 100% clear whether you only need a query or you want to do inserts. Anyway, this query with `NOT EXISTS` can be used as base for all necessary actions:

```
SELECT user_id, 5 AS permission 
FROM users u 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM permissions 
   WHERE permission = 5 AND user_id = u.user_id);
```

This will list all user id's that haven't yet a permission 5 and as second column, just 5 will be selected as permission.

Then this result can be used for whatever it should be used. For example to add this outcome in a query to the already present entries, `UNION ALL` can be used:

```
SELECT user_id, 5 AS permission 
FROM users u 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM permissions 
    WHERE permission = 5 AND user_id = u.user_id)
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id, permission 
FROM permissions
ORDER BY user_id, permission;
```

If - and I think this is your real question - the result of the `NOT EXISTS` query should be inserted into the permissions table, this insert command will do this:

```
INSERT INTO permissions 
  (SELECT user_id, 5 
  FROM users u 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 
    FROM permissions 
    WHERE permission = 5 AND user_id = u.user_id));
```

You can try out these things here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/baI8W-A_)

Comment: You don't need to add the condition permission = 5; the question is about finding users that does not have permissions. Thus, user_id = 3 should not have another permission level 5 because it has permission = 1 already

Comment: As I understand, all users should get permission 5. The author wrote "I want to add permission 5 to every single user who doesn't already have it" , not "I want to add permission 5 to every single user who doesn't already have another permission". But best would be if the author makes it clearer.

Comment: yeah, the word "it" is misleading. it can be permission OR permission=5.

Answer (score 0):

Below query will look for missing user id in permissions and insert new records in permissions table with a default permission equal to 5.

```
       INSERT INTO permissions
            (
                        user_id,
                        permission
            )
                   SELECT user_id,
                          5     AS permission
                   FROM   users  
                   WHERE  user_id NOT IN
                          (
                                 SELECT user_id
                                 FROM   permissions)
            )
```

Sample result:

| user_id | permission |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 0 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 |